# manipulating retrieved data using arrays

Tags: php, mysql

i am querying the DB as follows:

```
$result=mysql_query("SELECT name,items FROM mytable WHERE user_id='$id'");
```

now,i want to create an array to insert the values that are as a result of this query e'g let's say this is the resultant data:

```
name    quantity
john    10
joel    20
brian   10
```

1. how do I create an array to insert the above data using  $name and $quantity as variables;
2. secondly,(this is a trading platform),so let's say a user wanted to buy 25 items from the data in the array,and so to achieve this the script has  to take the 10 items  from john and 15 from joel(that adds up to 25) and then set their items to the remaining value i.e john's items=0 and joel's items=5.how do I code this.please assist. i've tried to simplify this the best i can .thanks

Comment: Insert the data where? Into an array (e.g. retrieve the database results into a PHP array?) or insert into another mysql table?

Comment: @Marc B yes, into a php array.kindly assist.thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[mysql_fetch_assoc](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-assoc.php) is your friend:

```
// Better turn on error_reporting
error_reporting(E_ALL); 
ini_set("display_errors", 1); 

// sp@20120227 - added the ')' at the end of the condition in the where part
$cursor = mysql_query( 'SELECT name,items '
                     . '  FROM mutable '
                     . ' WHERE ( user_id = "' . mysql_real_escape_string( $id ) . '" ) ' 
                     );

$foundItems = array();

// likely to be a parameter of a function...
$totalUnitsOrdered = 25;

// maps user to amount assigned from him
$assignedQuantityPerUser = array();


while ( $row = mysql_fetch_assoc( $cursor ) ) {

  // Still order Quantity left?
  if ( 0 < $totalUnitsOrdered ) {

    if ( $row[ "items" ] <= $totalUnitsOrdered ) {

       // assign all of $row[ "items" ]
       $totalUnitsOrdered                         -= 0 + $row[ "items" ];
       $assignedQuantityPerUser[ $row[ "name" ] ] += 0 + $row[ "items" ];

    }  else {

       // assign all the rest: $totalUnitsOrdered
       $totalUnitsOrdered                          = 0;
       $assignedQuantityPerUser[ $row[ "name" ] ] += $totalUnitsOrdered;

    }

  }


   $newItem[] = $row[ "name" ];
   $newItem[] = $row[ "items" ];

   // Append $newItem to the end of $foundItems 
   $foundItems[] = $newItem;

} // while
```

**Important:** Never pass user-input data directly into queries. Always espace using `mysql_real_escape_string()`!

Comment: thanks for that,,now how do i solve the second part using an associative or a multi-dimensional array?

Comment: .thanks a lot.however when i run the code i get an error about the $row[ "name" ] from this line being an undefined index,how do i solve this:
    $assignedQuantityPerUser[ $row[ "name" ] ] += 0 + $row[ "items" ];
 
 secondly,i want to update all the values in all the affected rows in the mysql table after completing the transcation,how do i do this so that all the affected rows(where items are deducted from) are updated?thanks a lot

Comment: I missed a ')' at the end of the where clause. Thus, mysql_fetch_assoc() didn't return anything useful. Just fixed it.

Comment: thanks.the problem arose because i did not initialize the value before using it.the code now runs well but the only problem is that i don't know how to update each of the affected values since the code just loops but the values in the DB don't change.how can i update each of the affected rows using MYSQL_UPDATE.THANKS.